# Ruby - Counter table with Cequel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cequel

I've started using [Cequel](https://github.com/cequel/cequel) in a project and I can't figure out how to work the Counters table. I have the following definition:

```
class Counter
  include Cequel::Record

  key :user_id, :text
  column :text, :counter
  column :int, :counter
  column :boolean, :counter
  column :timestamp, :counter
  column :tag, :counter
end
```

and it creates the table properly:

```
>> DESCRIBE counters ;

CREATE TABLE counters (
    user_id text PRIMARY KEY,
    visits counter,
    tweets counter
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

But when I try to create a record in the console I get:

```
INSERT statements are not allowed on counter tables, use UPDATE instead
```

I can see in the [tests](https://github.com/cequel/cequel/blob/master/spec/examples/metal/data_set_spec.rb#L333) that there is a way to increment but I can't find the right syntax. Anyone has experience setting this up and can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a different solution than the `Metal` way like in the tests. Posting here for others to use or if someone has a better solution.

```
Cequel::Record.connection[COUNTERS_TABLE].where(record_id: record_id).increment(field_name: 1)
```